# javax.mail.MessagingException while sending mail using JavaMail API

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send as email using JavaMail API, through my gmail account, but I am getting a javax.mail.MessagingException exception

The Code :

```
  public static Result sendMail() {

      Map < String, String[] > values = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();

      String toAddresses = values.get("toaddrs")[0];
      String subject = values.get("subject")[0];
      String body = values.get("body")[0];

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
              return new PasswordAuthentication("samplemail@gmail.com", "samplepass");
          }
      });

      try {

          Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("samplemail@gmail.com"));
          message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddresses));
          message.setSubject(subject);
          message.setText(body);

          Transport.send(message);
          return ok("sent");

      } catch (MessagingException e) {
          return ok("Error in sending email");
      }


  }
```

On debugging, I end up here in Service classs
[image: Service class]

which throws the exception : `javax.mail.MessagingException: Host, username, and password must be specified.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. The problem turned out to be a weird one, at least for a newbie like me. Simply put, I had exjello libraries in my classpath. They were messing with my JavaMail API. Once I created a new project and copied my code there, it worked fine. Just to check, I copied the exjello jars to my new project's classpath and it stopped working.

From a layman's point of view, it doesn't seem to be a good idea for a jar file to mess with my execution even though i had not even imported the package to my class.

Answer (score 1):

Correct these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  If it still doesn't work, post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: Thanks for this info and I have modified my code accordingly but I was wondering; Are these "mistakes" or best practices because my code works fine even if I use `Session.getDefaultInstance` contrary to what is specified. Same for the other points.

Comment: You can call them "best practices" if you like, but a lot of people have broken programs because of them.  Almost no one who does any of these things knows **why** they're doing it, they just cut and paste code from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The only differences that I can find with code that I am using to send to gmail (and which works) is this:

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();// get system props?
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

and 
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

you can also add: session.setDebug(true); this might give more clues.

On what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: on `Transport.send(message);`